# Node js error propagate to the caller

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a class with a instance function

// file1.js

```
export default class User {

constructor() {
this.userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
});
this.usermodel = Mongo.getModel('user', this.userSchema);
}

signUp({username, password}) {
var user = new this.usermodel({username: username,password: password});
this.usermodel.findOne({username: username}).exec((err, userresult) => {
  if (err) {
    /////////////// **LOCATION 1**: throw error that can be 
  } else {
    if(userresult) { // one user case so
      /////**LOCATION 2**: throw new Error("User with this Username already exists !. Please try a new Username.");
    } else { // null case
      return new DbResult({});
    }
  }
})
}

}
```

Another file file2 from which I am calling signUp of file1.

// file2.js

```
const user = new User();
try {
  user.signUp({username: request.body.username, password: request.body.password});
  console.log("reached means it is synchronous");
  response.status(200).json({'successmessage' : 'Successfully Signed Up'});
} catch (e) {
  response.status(400).json({'errormessage': e.message});
}
```

I want to just throw the error in file1.js at LOCATION 1 and 2 and I want to catch it in file2.js (from where it is called) and then handle it.

Can someone help how to do this ?
I am pretty new to nodejs .

I read about the fact that we cannot throw error inside callback just like that as it is a callback and it will only crash the code.
And I also read about this next, but I think I did not understand it properly and so don't know actually where to pass.
It will be nice if someone explains it and help me to solve this problem the right way .

Comment: You shouldn't throw *or* return values in the actual callback function as nothing can consume them. If you want to stick to callbacks, `signUp` should accept a callback function. If you hit an error, you'd do `return callback( err );`. Similarly, for a success, you'd do `return callback( null, value );`. Alternatively, you can use Promises and/or await/async. [I'd suggest you read about the three general approaches and decide which you prefer.](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee)

Comment: @vox, that was a great article. Solved it using promise now. Thank you so much for that article. That one is really valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Example of how you can do it with promise:

```
export default class User {

  constructor() {
    this.userSchema = new Schema({
      username: String,
      password: String,
    });
    this.usermodel = Mongo.getModel('user', this.userSchema);
  }

  signUp({username, password}) {
    var me = this;
    return new Promise(
      function(resolve,reject) {
        var user = new me.usermodel({username: username,password: password});
        me.usermodel.findOne({username: username}).exec((err, userresult) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            if(userresult) { // one user case so
              reject(new Error(
                "User with me Username already exists !. Please try a new Username."
              ));
            } else { // null case
              resolve(new DbResult({}));
            }
          }
        })    
      }
    )
  }  
}

const user = new User();
user.signUp({username: request.body.username, password: request.body.password})
.then(//success
  function(result){
    //do something with result
    response.status(200).json({'successmessage' : 'Successfully Signed Up'});
  }
)
.then(//fail
  undefined //no success handler
  ,function(err){
    //do something with error
    response.status(400).json({'errormessage': e.message});
  }
);
```